# Using the same cell in all collection views

Tags: ios

Probably a stupid question, but I could not find the answer to it yet.

How can I declare ONE template for collection view cell and then use it in ALL collection views? I'm using storyboard.

Because now I have 3 collection views that are the same (on 3 tab pages), which differ only in the data (all collection views use one datasource with different params). If I have to change some style, I have to do this 3 times...

Even better, if I can create some "user control" that inherits the collection view and use it everywhere I need (like fragments in Android or partial controls in asp.net mvc). Is it possible with storyboard? What is the right approach in my case?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is done the same way as a UITableViewCell

```
TTCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath;
```

Ray has some good tuts on the subject
[UICollectionView](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)

Comment: Will it work if template cell is defined in another storyboard's view and in another collection view? Thank you for the link!

Comment: Yes definitely. You need to create a class for your UICollectionViewCell so you can reuse that throughout the app. Although the layout of that cell will be created from the storyboard view so you still need to copy that cell to the other collectionView and change the cells class to your newly created class. Then you can use it like above. If you have a ton of collectionViews you can always create a Xib for just that collectionViewCell as well.

Comment: So I can mix storyboard with Xib items? I thought they were mutually exclusive...

Comment: Yes, use [_yourViewController initWithNibName:@"yournib" bundle:nil];